# Configure Build Service on build server with no TFS installed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have a Team Foundation Server 2012 installed. 
I want to configure the Build Service on another box which is the Build Server. The Build Server doesn't have TFS installed.

How should I setup the Build Service on the build server? Do I need to install Team Foundation Server first on it as well? I hope not....because when I run the tfs_server.exe from the install DVD I get the TFS install on the first screen. If I go ahead and hit Install Now...I will get the to the screen to configure Build Service without actually installing TF Server?

Answer (score 2):

To install Team Build you need to install, but not configure TFS on the server. The Install part will place all the binaries on the server, but will not actually install the web application, databases etc. Then in the configure phase you can just configure the Team Build part, which will configure your server to host and run the build service.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that the TF Server is 2012 version, but the Build Server has only Visual Studio 2010, framework 4.0. We don't do builds in 4.5 yet.

When I ran the install process on the Build Server to configure the Build Service on it, I installed the VS TFS 2012....with Framework 4.5. I have an issue with this because I don't want Framework 4.5 on the build machine. All the builds has to be done in VS 2005, 2008 and 2010 only.

Is that gonna be an issue now? Should I configure it from a TF Server 2010 install instead?

Comment: TFS 2012 has backwards compatibility with the TFS 2010 Build Controller and Agent, meaning you can configure a TFS 2010 Build Agent to build for a TFS 2012 server. Your TFS 2012 server should be at least at Update 2 for that to work, see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/03/30/team-foundation-server-2012-update-2-supports-2010-build-agents-and-controllers.aspx

Comment: this means that I have to install TFS 2010 on the build server, where I will have the agent. I just started with the TFS 2012 DVD....and installed the Framework 4.5...which I don't want. Am I on the right track by doing that?

Comment: On the build server, do not install any 2012 things, just Visual Studio 2010 and Team Build 2010 with all the latest updates.

Comment: I have this enterprise setup: The TF Server is 2012 with Update 3 on it (no Build service/controller/agents enabled on it). The Build Server has only VS2010 Ultimate with SP1, also with the Build service enabled and 1 controller and 4 agents on it. Now, I still cannot run the build definition. I keep getting TF900558: This build process template cannot be run on build server <My Build Server>-Controller. Upgrade this build server to a newer version. What should I do next? As far as I read, TFS2012 Update 2 (I hope Upd 3 as well) can accept build definitions from VS2010.Please help.Tkx.

Comment: You need to use the Build Process template XAML from 2010.